# Getting the number of days excluding years between two dates

Tags: mysql

I want to get the number of days ignoring year between two dates in MySql.

I am using the following query, which works fine when the dates are more than a year apart.

```
select dayofyear(from_days((to_days('2015-11-20') - to_days('2014-11-15'))))

select dayofyear(from_days((to_days('2019-11-20') - to_days('2014-11-15'))))
```

correctly both return 5

However when the two dates are in the same year

```
select dayofyear(from_days((to_days('2014-11-20') - to_days('2014-11-15'))))
```

this returns 0. I think this is because MySql has a problem with dates in years less than 100 (or at least the dayofyear function has).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Please update your question to specify what you want to happen wrt leap years. What is the desired number of days between, say, 2012-02-27 and 2013-03-01? How about the number of days between 2012-02-27 and 2012-03-01? How about between 2013-02-27 and 2017-03-01?

Comment: What about wraparounds?  What do you want for 2015-02-23 to 2016-02-22?  What about 2015-02-23 to 2016-02-23?

Comment: I want it to return the number of days between two dates. So if 7 years and 34 days I want 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent your willingness to specify what happens on leap years, one is forced to guess.

I think this works.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/043543/1/0

```
IF(timestampdiff(DAY, st, str_to_date(concat_ws('-',YEAR(st),MONTH(fi), DAY(fi)),'%Y-%m-%d')) >= 0,
   timestampdiff(DAY, st, str_to_date(concat_ws('-',YEAR(st),MONTH(fi), DAY(fi)),'%Y-%m-%d')),
   timestampdiff(DAY, st, str_to_date(concat_ws('-',YEAR(st)+1,MONTH(fi), DAY(fi)),'%Y-%m-%d'))) delta
```

It tacks the starting year onto the ending day and tries to compute the number of days. Then, if that comes up negative, it tacks the year after the starting year onto the starting day and computes the number of days.

Answer (score 1):

You are complicating this issue for nothing;

There is a `DATEDIFF` function in MySQL that allow you to do that.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-03','2006-04-01');
```

That would return 2 (days).

To get the result regardless of the year, then apply % 365.

**Edit :** If you want to get the exact number of days considering leap years, you could substract to the number of days, the number of days for both year at 1st january (or any other date) :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-03','2006-04-01') - DATEDIFF(concat(year(yourDate), '01-01'), concat(year(yourDate2), '01-01'));
```

This will substract the total number of days between 1st january of each year to the total number of days.

Comment: Not every year has 365 days!

Comment: I know that, but your request is supposed to be regardless of year.

Comment: No its the number of days I want so 26 years and 101 days I want 101

Comment: Divide by 364.25 and you should be close enought to don't care.

Comment: I do care though it would be a day out maybe two for some 100 year date ranges

Comment: Divide by 365.2425 and you will be exact unless you span the Julian-Greorian conversion.